# Magento - Display Wishlist button to registered users only

Tags: magento, cart

I have been searching around several threads and found a couple posts that allowed me to put together a solution, but I'm having a syntax problem.

There is an "add all to wishlist" button on my cart page that I want to display to logged in customers only.

I found this on another thread:

```
if($this->helper(‘customer’)->isLoggedIn()){
//block1
} else {
//block2
}
```

This works, but when I enter the code for my "block1", which is the button I need to display in that case, everything breaks.

This is the code for my "block1":

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('A&ntilde;adir todos a Lista de Compras') ?>" class="button btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost').$params?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('A&ntilde;adir todo a Lista de Compras') ?></span></span></button>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you try like that $urlwithpar = 'checkout/cart/updatePost' . $params; setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl($urlwithpar) ?>')

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('A&ntilde;adir todos a Lista de Compras') ?>" class="button btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl("checkout/cart/updatePost").$params?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('A&ntilde;adir todo a Lista de Compras') ?></span></span></button>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I've tried this but it doesn't work. The whole page goes blank when I try it.

Comment: I've just copied and pasted this code on one of my websites and it works well. However I've noticed that in the code which works for you you are using ‘ instead of ' (which is the opposite of what works for me). So try changing ' to ‘ and maybe this will fix it. I had that issue some time ago after copying a snippet from a website.

Comment: Hi @marcinsdance, thanks again for the reply. Could you please paste the whole block of code as it works on your site? I think I have a syntax problem with the echo inside another echo. Thanks!

Comment: The code which works for me is the one in my answer. I've just copied and pasted it and it worked immediately. Again, you need to make sure you use the correct apostrophes. So maybe best would be to enter type the whole text again, to make sure there are no weird characters instead. This sometimes happen if you copy a code from somewhere.